# Chocolatey parameters for dependent packages

Tags: chocolatey

Do the '--params' passed to 'choco install' command are accessible/available to 'dependent' packages? My package 'B' has a dependency on package 'A', when package 'A' is being installed I want to access the parameters (--params) passed to package 'B'. My tests show that accessing the parameters during package 'A' install using 'Get-PackageParameters' or '$env:ChocolateyPackageParameters' returns nothing (if package 'A' is being installed as part of dependency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default any `--params` parameters are passed to the .install / .portable version of the same package name.

The parameter you are looking for is `--paramsglobal` which passes parameters to all dependent packages. For completeness there is also an `--argsglobal` parameter which does the same but for installers inside dependent packages.

`--paramsglobal` is what you are looking for.